# Meaning of Supermicro firmware update error messages

Tags: bios, supermicro

Flashing the 1.1a BIOS update for the [Abit A2SDi-8C+-HLN4F](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/atom/A2SDi-8C_-HLN4F.cfm) seems to work but there are some error messages:

```
Reading flash ... done
- ME Data Size checking ... ok
- FFS checksums .... ok
- Check RomLayout ... Ok
Erasing Boot Block ... done
Updating Boot Block ... done
Verifying Boot Block ... done
Erasing Main Block ... done
Updating Main Block ... done
Verifying Main Block ... done
Erasing NVRAM Block ... done
Updating NVRAM Block ... done
Verifying NVRAM Block ... done
Erasing NCB Block ... done
Updating NCB Block ... done
Verifying NCB Block ... done
- FDR is locked, skip updating.
- Update success for GBEA...
- Update success for GBEB...
- Flash Update Error at address 0xFF11E000 !!
c2 - Error: Region is write-protected
```

After a reboot, the machine is still usable and the BIOS displays the 1.1a version, thus, the update seems to have (mostly?) succeeded.

But what is the meaning of the above error messages?

What is an FDR and why is it locked?

Why is there a certain (unexpected) write-protected region?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the rest of your questions, but I found some [AMI Firmware Update documentation](https://download.irbis.su/%23fw.tablets.windows/BIOS/TW81_BIOS_EFI/readme.txt) that says that FDR stands for Flash-Descriptor Region.